# MuleSoft 4 Anypoint Studio Dynamic Database Query Parameter Error

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I have to use a dynamic query to set the schema/library name for a database query and Anypoint Studio 7.4.1 keeps throwing an error stating that it is "unable to resolve value for the parameter: sql".

I'm following this doc https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/db/database-connector-examples#dynamic-queries.

It works, fine when I run it, but is there a way to get AnyPoint to stop showing the error?

Here is the XML

```
    <flow name="GetLinks" doc:id="c1f17deb-98f2-4261-93ec-cf785e310892" >
        <set-variable value="${db.dataLibrary}" doc:name="Set Library" doc:id="2a5cebbb-3047-4ede-ab0d-7a7257427e7e" variableName="library"/>
        <db:select doc:name="Select EP0001F1" doc:id="ecf2a61f-4e14-4b00-beb1-546d2fa1ba8f" config-ref="Database_Config" fetchSize="100" maxRows="500">
            <db:sql >#[&quot;select * from $(vars.library).EP0001F1 order by EPDRC desc&quot;]</db:sql>
        </db:select>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="c3b8bcb4-20ef-4b86-a4cd-585e7f57e6d0" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    loginId: trim(payload01.EPLOGINID),
    individualId: trim(payload01.EPIID),
    officeNumber: payload01.EPOFID,
    controlNumber: payload01.EPICN,
    webControlNumber: payload01.EPWCN,
    lastUpdatedBy: trim(payload01.EPULU)
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
```

[image: Flow showing error]
[image: Flow properties]

The stacktrace for the error shows

```
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "You called the function '' with these arguments: 
  1: Null (null)
  2: String (".EP0001F1 order by EPDRC desc")

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: String
  2: String

Trace:
  at main (Unknown)" evaluating expression: ""select * from $(vars.library).EP0001F1 order by EPDRC desc"".
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.el.ExpressionExecutionException: You called the function '' with these arguments: 
  1: Null (null)
  2: String (".EP0001F1 order by EPDRC desc")

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: String
  2: String

Trace:
  at main (Unknown)
```

Comment: The [Salesforce Connector - Query](https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.10/salesforce-connector-reference#query) has the same problem.  Error: `org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ValueResolvingException: Unable to resolve value for the parameter: salesforceQuery...`

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct. Did a small sample and tested it out.
This is how I wrote my query, and it worked for me.

`#["SELECT * FROM $(vars.schema). TEST_TABLE"]`

The error tells me that your variable is null. Just make sure that your variable is initialized with proper value before using it in the query. May be, just put that in logger and make sure your var. Library has something in it.

[image: Flow with Connector of MuleSoft for Set Variable, Database Select, Transform Message]

***Note***: I tested it with order by in my query as well and that works too. I tested it against Microsoft SQL Server. Also, I got that error only when my var was null. (I got the same error)

Comment: I'm confused by "almost correct"; I am not seeing a difference in the query. I am not getting the error at runtime, it is only at design time and it looks like you are getting the same error. Your comment about it being null makes me think that Studio is not understanding the variable is there. Even hard coding the variable in the "Set Variable" component does not remove it. I've added a "Is Not Null" check on it and that does not remove it either.

Answer (score 1):

I've contacted support and they have replicated the issue. 
They said that its a DataSense error because it cannot reference the metadata at design time, even though it works at runtime. 
They also said that it should not be presenting an error in the flow. 
They have submitted it as a defect, so hopefully it will get patched soon.